# PHP Xpath Query with Attribute That Has Colon Not Working

Tags: php, xpath

With this Xpath:

```
//*[@data-auto='citation_field_value'][@xmlns:extendedmarkupcontroller='urn:ExtendedMarkupController']
```

I was hoping to retrieve this element:

```
<dd data-auto="citation_field_value" xmlns:extendedmarkupcontroller="urn:ExtendedMarkupController">Freeman, Michael K., author</dd>
```

However, nothing was returned with:

```
$xpatho = new DOMXpath($doc);
$elementsn =  $xpatho->query($xpath);
```

$elementsn->length gave me 0.

Why is this so? Is it because of the colon? and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The ':' means that your document is using namespaces, and namespaces change the world.

For starters, a namespace declaration in the source XML (like `xmlns:extendedmarkupcontroller="urn:ExtendedMarkupController"`) does not become an attribute node in the XDM data model, so you cannot access it using the attribute axis (or the '@' shorthand for the attribute axis). If you want to find an element whose name is in this namespace, then the correct predicate to use is

```
[namespace-uri()='urn:ExtendedMarkupController']
```

In your example, though, the element *declares* the namespace, but it doesn't actually *use* the namespace. Testing whether an element declares a particular namespace, when that namespace isn't actually used, is a rather unusual requirement. You can do it with the namespace axis:

```
[namespace::extendedmarkupcontroller="urn:ExtendedMarkupController"]
```

though some XPath processors don't fully implement the spec in this area.

This should be enough for this particular problem, but if you're starting to work with namespaces I would recommend reading around the subject before you write any more code, because there are lots of pitfalls.